# How do I debug a stack overflow?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, stack-overflow, delphi-5, reportbuilder

I was wondering if anyone has had a similar experience. I am trying to trace the source of a problem but am coming up with nil. I have a project in Delphi 5 which has Report Builder reports on it. I needed an upgraded version of reportbuilder so I tried running the project in Delphi 7. When my project runs and I click a button to view a report, it views fine. However, if I use a paramstr to run the report (showmainform is set false) and show report procedure runs, I get get a stack overflow error.

The original code was :

```
 if lowercase(ParamStr(1)) = 'termsexceeded' then begin
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.close;
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.open;
    reports.ppTermsExceeded.print;
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.close;
    application.terminate;
  end;
```

And it gave me the stack overflow error on the .print function.

The code that works in Delphi 7 is :

```
 if lowercase(ParamStr(1)) = 'termsexceeded' then begin
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.close;
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.open;
    reports.left := -10000;
    reports.show;
    reports.ppTermsExceeded.print;
    reportsdata.termsexceeded.close;
    application.terminate;
  end;
```

Has anybody got a suggestion on how I could debug this to see if the problem lies with my Delphi 7 or with Reportbuilder ?

There are no events on the .show event of the reports form.

Any advice on how to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: On a sidenote, why do you need to set `reports.left := -10000;` ?

Comment: The form that holds the report is a blank form so showing it looks untidy, so I set it out of user sight.

Comment: Where does this code live? What invokes it? Is it in the main .dpr file?

Comment: This code lives inside the main form of the application but the report component is on the reports form

Answer (score 8):

When you get a stack overflow, use the debugger. It will interrupt your program when the OS throws the exception, and at that time, you can use the debugger's *call stack* window to see the path a function calls that lead there. You'll probably see a certain function or sequence of functions repeated many times.

When you've found the repeating pattern, check the code to see why it's repeating. Look for a condition is supposed to have changed, but doesn't.

Comment: Thanks I did try that , but each code snippet it stepped into that seemed to be recurring, I removed (each time I removed an offending unit, another one occurred), until there was no more but the actual print routine. I have now resorted to just showing that form and have no hassles, would just like a definitive reason as too the error.